# Running multiple values through excel calculation

Tags: excel, vba

Another member of my team has built the elaborate spreadsheet that calculates a certain value we need. However, it's currently set up like so:

- Change the values in cells A1, A2, A3.
- A bunch of interdependent calculations happen, populating several hundred cells. Those hundred cells, then get merged through another formula back into the value I need.
- Useful output appears in cell D1

My task is to generate a series of what ifs. If A1 = 4, A2 = 4.7, A3 = 0.2, what would D1 be?

Repeat that for the 10k+ other valid combinations of A1, A2, and A3 while logging the outputs.

My instinct was just to treat it like a function in a programming language and make it a function that takes the inputs and spits out an output... however I'm not sure how to do that. Any guidance on how this can be done? The function the coworker runs is very complicated, so it's not easy to replicate that logic across multiple rows or columns as far as "drag and drop" like I might do for a SUM or something.

Comment: Is the function that your co-worker designed in a cell? Or is it a macro that runs at the click of a button? The answer to that is going to tell you where the "magic" can be found. Once you know the formula, then you can loop through the values to arrive at the whole range of possible answers. How many input cells are we talking about here?

Comment: You could write a script which enters your 10k+ valid combos into `A1:A3` one-combo-at-a-time and also records the result from `D1` before moving to the next combo. This would not be difficult.

Comment: @SmrtGrunt, It's all in cell. I guess it's the looping through part that I don't really know. I rarely use excel and only really know the "drag and drop" stuff.

Comment: This question is far too vague and broad in scope. We don't know what *magic happens* means. Examine what your team member has designed, and if you're unclear what it's doing ask that team member to explain. Once you've got an understanding of what exactly is happening, you're in a position to consider the possibilities that are available to automate it.

Comment: @MichaelMurphy Could you point me to an example of that type of script? I assume it exists, but I just have no idea what to search for in order to find that and things like, "update cells in calculation excel" have led me nowhere.

Comment: I would organize my 10,000 combos in a worksheet with 3 columns and 10k rows. I would store these combos in a 2D variant array from that range. I would loop through the rows of this array, enter three values at a time into the target cells, and record the result in a cell in another sheet, then record the next result in the cell below until I have 10,000 results. Search for `"For Loops"`, `"Variant Array from Range"`, `"Range Object"` for more info.

Comment: If you could give us some idea of what the several hundred other cells are doing, that also would help us direct your search. Is it matrix manipulation, some other optimization, or just a field of values from which to gather basic statistics such as median or standard deviation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to Michael Murphy in the comments which gave me some things to search. I'm leaving this here so future people searching can find it.

```
Sub test()
'
' test Macro
'
    Dim a_array As Variant
    Dim b_array As Variant
    Dim c_array As Variant
    Dim rw_cnt As Integer

    rw_cnt = 2
    ' This selects each of the things to combo
    a_array = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2:A5")
    b_array = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B2:B5")
    c_array = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C2:C5")

    For Each a_el In a_array
        For Each b_el In b_array
            For Each c_el In c_array
                worth = compute_worth(a_el, b_el, c_el)
                ' This writes the output where we can track it
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(rw_cnt, 6) = a_el
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(rw_cnt, 7) = b_el
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(rw_cnt, 8) = c_el
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(rw_cnt, 9) = worth
                rw_cnt = rw_cnt + 1
            Next a_el
        Next b_el
    Next c_el
End Sub


Function compute_worth(a, b, c)
    ' This puts the value into the original sheet then extracts the output
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = a
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2") = b
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A3") = c
    worth = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D1").Value
    compute_worth = worth
End Function
```